# What happened in the 5 years between Kazusa's Route end and his True Route end?

Tags: white-album-2

How the visual novel ends in the Kazusa route, after Kazusa goes to Europe? what happens in his 5 years of absence and how his True route ends.

I have not read the visual novel and only know the end of the anime.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about the gameplay itself.  It *might* have a better time on Arqade; please check their FAQ first.

Comment: @Makoto Isn't this question about the story of the game and therefore allowed here?

Comment: @Turamarth:  It could be; I could be convinced.  I read it as, "how does the game end", which may be a crazy oversimplification.

Comment: [Related questions on Kazusa](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bwhite-album-2%5d%20kazusa%20is%3aq), some related to the anime ending and true route end.